# My openpyxl script seems to corrupt the original file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, openpyxl

I tried to write a script that will read excel template file i have with Openpyxl, generate barcode image with Python-barcode library. and then write that image back to excel. But i got the error and it corrupted the original excel files.

I have no idea what's causing it. Searching Google and all i found was a solution for Flask case which seems different than mine. The rest are I/O Operation error.

Here's my code

```
def test_room():
    root = Tk()
    root.excel = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select Excel', filetypes=(("Excel", "*.xlsx"),('All Files','*.*')))
    worksheet = openpyxl.load_workbook(root.excel, data_only=True)
    sheet = worksheet.sheetnames
    sticker_front = worksheet[sheet[0]]
    sticker_side = worksheet[sheet[1]]
    all_data = worksheet[sheet[2]]  
    col1_tolist = []
    col2_tolist = []

    for val in range(1, all_data.max_row+1):
        col1 = all_data.cell(row=val, column=1).value
        col1 = f'No.{col1}'
        col2 = all_data.cell(row=val, column=2).value
        col3 = all_data.cell(row=val, column=3).value
        col1_tolist.append(col1)
        col2_tolist.append(col2)

        def template_front1(): #top left
            if len(col1_tolist) % 4 == 1:
                sticker_front['A1'].value = col1_tolist[0]
                sticker_front['A2'].value = col2_tolist[0]
                with open(rf"D:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\result\{col3}.png".replace("/00","-00"), "wb+") as files:
                    Code128(col3, writer=ImageWriter()).write(files)
                    img1 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(files)
                    img1.height = 76
                    img1.width = 163
                    sticker_front.add_image(img1, 'A3')
                worksheet.save(root.excel)
        template_front1()
```

When i run the code, i got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\barcodeprint.py", line 148, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\barcodeprint.py", line 94, in main
    template_front1()
  File "d:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\barcodeprint.py", line 47, in template_front1
    worksheet.save(root.excel)
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 77, in write_data
    self._write_images()
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 116, in _write_images
    self._archive.writestr(img.path[1:], img._data())
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py", line 48, in _data
    img = _import_image(self.ref)
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\drawing\image.py", line 16, in _import_image
    img = PILImage.open(img)
  File "C:\Users\Comseven\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3096, in open
    fp.seek(0)
ValueError: seek of closed file
```

If i tried "wb+" in "wb" or "rb" i will have similar error to above. Except the last line is something along the line of

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: read
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I manage to solve the problem on my own.

I don't know if it's have something to do with how Barcode Library implemented writing procedure by closing it right after finish writing.Or how Openpyxl close the PIL image file, thus prevented me from reading the file again. But turns out if i just remove indent on

```
    with open(rf"D:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\result\{col3}.png".replace("/00","-00"), "wb+") as files:
        Code128(col3, writer=ImageWriter()).write(files)
        img1 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(files)
        img1.height = 76
        img1.width = 163
        sticker_front.add_image(img1, 'A3')
    worksheet.save(root.excel)
```

template_front1()

to

```
        with open(rf"D:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\result\{col3}.png".replace("/00","-00"), "wb+") as files:
            Code128(col3, writer=ImageWriter()).write(files)
        img1 = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(rf"D:\Workstuff\my-work-python-script\Print Barcode (dev)\result\{col3}.png".replace("/00","-00"))
        img1.height = 76
        img1.width = 163
        sticker_front.add_image(img1, 'A3')
        worksheet.save(root.excel)
template_front1()
```

and replace `files` write buffer into path string. It just works...